# Is it ok to temporarily store a password (string) in a cookie using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress

I know the answer is generally no for doing this, but I will be deleting the cookie immediately after running a function. What I have is a function that registers a user (WordPress), then sends data to Pardot, then on the page redirection I want it to log you in using the password you registered with.

I have a function below which registers you fine, it just doest then log you in:

```
function register_user_form() {
    $user_login = $_POST['currentUserName'];
    $user_email = $_POST['currentUserEmail'];
    $user_pass = $_POST['currentUserPassword'];

    $userdata = compact( 'user_login', 'user_email', 'user_pass' );
    $user = wp_insert_user($userdata);
    $creds = array('user_login' => $user_login, 'user_password' => $user_pass, 'remember' => true);
    $user = wp_signon($creds);

}
add_action('wp_ajax_register_user_form', 'register_user_form');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_register_user_form', 'register_user_form');
```

So on form submit, I would save the cookie, then after the page is redirected back from Pardot, I will log you in using the cookie data, then immediately delete the cookie.

Comment: No, never expose passwords ouside of your server.

Comment: You may want to look at this sample project I created a while back. This is sometimes called `federation` https://github.com/bluebrown/jwt-exchange-authentication

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend this solution, but if you really have to do it for some reason, make sure to encrypt it before storing, and decrypt it when reading. That's what I'm doing when just sending passwords from backend to frontend and vice versa. Here is a guide: https://gist.github.com/nim4n136/7fa38467181130f5a2270c39d495101e.

In the given code, you can see the encrypt function which will use salt (random value), which is hashed with the password, using sha256. Salt (not encrypted) is returned to the main function which you can save to a cookie. Upon reading the cookie, pass it to the decrypt method, which will use the previously generated salt to decrypt it. You can also use some encryption key, not visible to the frontend, as a salt, that way it's not stored alongside with hashed password.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this certainly is a valid answer, please [edit] it to include the key points of the code you've linked along some explanation. Thanks!